# Expand a power series using derivatives

Tags: derivatives, power-series

The exercise I need to do is to open $f(z) = \frac{1}{(4-z)^3}$ as a power series of $(z-2)$. Then represent graphically the convergence disk

I started by expanding $f(z) = \frac{1}{(4-z)}$ like:

$$
\frac{1}{(4-z)} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-(\frac{z-2}{2})}
$$
Therefore, I get $a = \frac{1}{2}$ and the new $z = \frac{z-2}{2}$. So, for writing the power series, I got $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}*\left(\frac{z-2}{2}\right)^n$, then it transforms to $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}*\left(z-2\right)^n$

From here, how do I do the derivative to get to $\frac{1}{(4-z)^3}$ ? Do I pick the expression inside the summation and derive as:

$$
\frac{1}{(4-z)^2} = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}* n * \left(z-2\right)^{n-1}
$$

And then derive again to get $\frac{1}{(4-z)^3}$ ?

EDIT - final answer:

According to @Dave answer, the final answer is:

$$
\frac{1}{(4-z)^3} = \frac{\sum\limits_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}* n * (n-1) * \left(z-2\right)^{n-2}}{2}
$$
Because the derivative of $\frac{1}{(4-z)^2}$ = $\frac{2}{(4-z)^3}$, and then we need to fix the index to $n = 2$

So in the final part, we get

$$
\sum\limits_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n+2}}* n * (n-1) * \left(z-2\right)^{n-2}
$$

Comment: Yes. You may differentiate a power series term by term as many times as you like, just make sure you start the sum at the right index (constant term becomes zero when you differentiate).

Comment: @Dave could you please check if this last edit part is right? Also, the convergence radius is 2

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: Yes that answer is correct. Differentiating (or integrating) power series can be done term by term any number of times and the radius of convergence remains the same. There is a theorem on that